# Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'

Tags: flutter-dependencies

I'm working on a route map app with Flutter using google_maps_webservice,location,map_view package after run

Launching lib\main.dart on SAMSUNG SM G530AZ in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Android dependency 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base' has different version for the compile (15.0.1) and runtime (16.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 11s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly after sevral day i've found, the package map_view have many  dependencies conflict between the migration androidX and android.support: so instead of continue using mapview I'm using cirrus_map_view the correction version of map_view and it work!